# Recaptcha not display in Contact Form7

Tags: wordpress

Did not display in recaptcha contact form 7 . But displayed the right side corner recaptcha in website. how to rectify this error?

Comment: How did you add recaptcha? contact form 7 requires reCAPTCHA addon integration.